# Why are properties undefined after using bind function (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, pointers, undefined, bind

Here is the link to the MDN explanation of function.prototype.bind() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

I added some console.logs to help me understand what was happening.

```
var module = {
    x: 42,
    getX: function() {
        return this.x;
    }
};

var boundGetX = module.getX.bind(module);

console.log(boundGetX());
console.log(boundGetX().x);
console.log(boundGetX.x);
```

The first console.log returns

```
42
```

This makes sense to me.

However, the second and third console.logs return

```
undefined
```

Why is that? How can the function be able to see and log the module property, x, with its stored value of 42, and yet the `boundGetX` value for x is undefined?

After using the bind function, isn't `boundGetX` now pointing to `module.getX` AND the 'this' variable pointing to module?

Why wouldn't `boundGetX.x` point to `module.x`? And how is it capable of successfully logging the value of `module.x` when `boundGetX.x` is undefined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call:

```
console.log(boundGetX().x);
```

You are essentially calling:

```
this.x.x
```

Which is actually doing:

```js
(42).x // there's no property x on the number 42
```

And since there's no property `x` on the property `x`, it's `undefined`.

Comment: Okay. I think I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   **this** keyword set to the **provided value**, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

[bind function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) changes the meaning of `this` and in your case you are setting `module` to resolve as `this` in your `getX` function:

```
getX: function() {
   return this.x;   // <-- this is now `module` object so `x` resolves to 42
}
```

This is why `console.log(boundGetX());` now prints `42` since you are essentially printing `module.x` via the `module.getX` function.

Now these two:

```
console.log(boundGetX().x);
console.log(boundGetX.x);
```

Make no sense anymore since you bound `boundGetX` to the `getX` function and that function does not have `x` property nor returns `x` property, it just returns a the **value of x**.

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful.